# How to search for all tabs between two quotation marks with grep / egrep

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression, tabulation

I'm looking for all tabs between two quotation marks with grep / egrep in a bash.

I tried

```
grep -r . -e "\".*\t.*\""
grep -r . -e "\".*\\t.*\""
grep -r . -e "\".*\\\\t.*\""
grep -r . -e '\".*\t.*\"'
grep -r . -e '\".*\\t.*\"'
grep -r . -e '".*\t.*"'
grep -r . -e '".*\\t.*"'
```

But I don't get the desired result. Following `grep`s yield all line with a `\t`:

```
grep -r . -e "\".*\\\\t.*\""
grep -r . -e '\".*\\t.*\"'
grep -r . -e '".*\\t.*"'
```

Following `grep`s yield all line with a `t`:

```
grep -r . -e "\".*\t.*\""
grep -r . -e "\".*\\t.*\""
grep -r . -e '".*\t.*"'
grep -r . -e '\".*\t.*\"'
```

But none of these searches for a real tabulator. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU `grep` (which I assume you are using), does not know `\t` as a tab by default.  In a POSIX regular expression, `\t` would match a literal `t`, and `\\t` would match `\t`.

To match a literal tab character with a POSIX regular expression, insert one in your expression:

```
grep -r $'".*\t.*"' .
```

This uses `$'...'` in `bash` to expand the escape sequences in the string to their corresponding meaning in the C language.

If you enable Perl-like regular expressions (PCRE) with `-P` in GNU `grep`, it will recognise `\t` as a tab character in the expression:

```
grep -P -r '".*\t.*"' .
```

Note too that your expression would match

```
"hello" <tab> "world"
```

Comment: Note that GNU `grep` knows `\t` as tab with `-P` (if enabled).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. Added.

Comment: Note that in a POSIX regexp, while `grep '[\t]'` is required to match on backslash and `t`, `grep '\t'` is unspecified, so implementations are free to match TAB if they like. Some do like ast-open's